# Library for simulating HTTP transactions like a browser with cookie and session support

Tags: .net, http, session, cookies

I wonder if there is a .NET library that mimics a browser in terms of HTTP transactions. In other words I am going to make multiple GET/POST requests and I want the cookies to be persisted to a storage, so that consecutive request will be identified by the remote host. AFAIK [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) has support for this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in [System.Net.HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class has support for cookies, but they are disabled by default for security reasons. You can enable them and persist them using [CookieContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler).  Its actually a debugging proxy which is handy for capturing an initial conversation.  Its built in .NET and is quite scriptable in .NET languages.